# How do I remove part of a string in python list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have this output of code (used keyboard module):

```
[KeyboardEvent(enter up), KeyboardEvent(h down), KeyboardEvent(h up), KeyboardEvent(e down), KeyboardEvent(e up), KeyboardEvent(y down), KeyboardEvent(y up)]
```

How can I remove every 'KeyboardEvent' from this list?

Comment: Please be clear about your list elements.  There appear to be no strings in this list; rather they're objects (individual instances of class KeyboardEvent).

Comment: The easiest way is just `list = []`. Is there a specific event that contains a certain keyboard action (such as "enter up") that you want removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using [`KeyboardEvent.name`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardeventname%60):

```
newList = [event.name for event in myList]
```

To get an even better result you can combine this with [`KeyboardEvent.event_type`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardeventevent_type):

```
newList = [event.name + ' ' + event.event_type for event in myList]
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> myList
[KeyboardEvent(enter up), KeyboardEvent(h down), KeyboardEvent(h up), KeyboardEvent(e down), KeyboardEvent(e up), KeyboardEvent(y down)]

>>> [event.name for event in myList]
['enter', 'h', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'y']

>>> [event.name + ' ' + event.event_type for event in myList]
['enter up', 'h down', 'h up', 'e down', 'e up', 'y down']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a=[KeyboardEvent(enter up), KeyboardEvent(h down), KeyboardEvent(h up), KeyboardEvent(e down), KeyboardEvent(e up), KeyboardEvent(y down), KeyboardEvent(y up)]
a=[elem for elem in a if not isinstance(a, KeyboardEvent)]
```

This list comprehesion should work

Comment: Can't blame you for doing exactly what he asked, but this will produce an empty list, and that is clearly not the goal.

Comment: @ChristianDean I did not know that. Could you explain why?

Comment: @ChristianDean, is this what you wanted?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Sure. It's preferred because `instance` takes subclasses into account, while `type` does not. Here's the relevant [part from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

Answer (score 3):

I would try regular expressions

```
import re

Foo = [KeyboardEvent(enter up), KeyboardEvent(h down), KeyboardEvent(h up), KeyboardEvent(e down), KeyboardEvent(e up), KeyboardEvent(y down), KeyboardEvent(y up)]

strList = []

for item in Foo:
  bar = re.sub('KeyboardEvent(\(.*?)', '', str(item))
  bar = re.sub('\)', '', bar)
  strList.append(bar)

print strList
```

Comment: Works fine but i still like @Vinícius Aguiar answer more.Upvote anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this using a loop:

```
list = [KeyboardEvent(enter up), KeyboardEvent(h down), KeyboardEvent(h up), KeyboardEvent(e down), KeyboardEvent(e up), KeyboardEvent(y down), KeyboardEvent(y up)]

for x in list:
    del list[str(x)]
```

Comment: What if it isn't a keyboard event?

Comment: It will still work. It works for deleting anything in a list/array.

Comment: then you may as well use `list=[]`

Comment: True, much simpler.

Comment: It's not recommended to use list as a variable name in Python

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try this which actually removes the KeyBoard event as a string:

```
a=[KeyboardEvent(enter up), KeyboardEvent(h down), KeyboardEvent(h up), KeyboardEvent(e down), KeyboardEvent(e up), KeyboardEvent(y down), KeyboardEvent(y up)]
a=[str(elem).strip('KeyboardEvent') for elem in a]
```

Comment: ['(enter up), KeyboardEvent(h down), KeyboardEvent(h up), KeyboardEvent(e down), KeyboardEvent(e up), KeyboardEvent(y down), KeyboardEvent(y up)'] , it only removes the first one.